# CDN for JQGRID bootstrap css

Tags: jqgrid, bootstrap-modal, cdn

Is there any cdns available for JQGrid bootstrap css? I want to integrage bootstrap with my JQGrid.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend from what fork of jqGrid you use. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork after renaming of jqGrid from Guriddo jqGrid JS, changing the license agreement and making it commercial. See [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) and the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334).

Gurrido and free jqGrid have different priorities. As I know, Gurrido will be published only on bower.

I publish all versions of free jqGrid on two CDNs: [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/free-jqgrid) and [jsDelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!free-jqgrid). Moreover I publish all versions on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) and on [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) and it's deployed on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid) too. It makes the usage of free jqGrid mostly easy. I see CDN as the preferred way of usage. One can read on [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and to see the suggested for of usage [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html).

Free jqGrid supports Bootstrap by adding `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` option. You can combine the option with `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` if CSS with [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) is included. Alternatively one can use `iconSet: "glyph"` if you prefer to use [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs) font. *No separate "bootstrap css"* exist in free jqGrid. One need just include `ui.jqgrid.min.css` or `ui.jqgrid.css`, which included all CSS rules required.